# Concurrency setting bounds

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm pretty new to Concurrency but get this gist of it at the moment; I have a program that is **NOT Thread Safe**, so that it is possible that the invariant of the class mainly the lower bound is less than on equal to the upper bound can be broken.
I have come up with a little main method hoping it would print out false when this is true but cannot figure why it wont.

```
public class Conc implements Runnable {

    // Invariant: lower <= upper
    private final AtomicInteger lower = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final AtomicInteger upper = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void setLower(int l) {
        if (l <= upper.get())
            lower.set(l);
    }

    public void setUpper(int u) {
        if (u >= lower.get())
            upper.set(u);
    }

    public boolean isInRange(int i) {
        return (i >= lower.get() && i <= upper.get());
    }

    public boolean invariantSatisfied() {
        return (lower.get() <= upper.get());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Conc());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Conc());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Conc());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            setUpper(i - 10000);
            setLower(i + 800000);
            if (invariantSatisfied() == false) {
                System.out.println("False");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're using 'new' on Conc and you don't share any object between threads, hence, it's safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with this program that are causing the unexpected results.

The first as has been pointed out is that the code is actually thread safe.
This is because each Object has it's own set of fields that they are referring to and each thread has it's own object.

This can be fixed in a couple of ways

you can use the same object in each thread

```
  Conc target = new Conc ();
  Thread t1 = new Thread(target);
  Thread t2 = new Thread(target);
  Thread t3 = new Thread(target);
  t1.start();
  t2.start();
  t3.start();
```

or you could make the fields static which would mean there is only ever one instance

```
private static final AtomicInteger lower = new AtomicInteger(0);
private static final AtomicInteger upper = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

The other issue you have is that even if this program was not thread safe the the window for the test to fail is so small that it would rarely if ever fail due to the input data.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    setUpper(i);
    setLower(i);
    if(!invariantSatisfied()){
        System.out.println("False");
    }
}
```

fixes that.

Comment: I think it is possible for the `setUpper(i - 10000); setLower(i + 800000);` version to print false, but your version does it much more consistently.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the threads you provide to each one a new instance of `Conc` class. Which means that there is concurrent access to `lower` and `upper` instance variables, each thread has its own.
So you do not have a concurrency issue here, is more like a problem with your algorithm.
The code is thread-safe.